# Selection Sort - Can we delete the intermediate variable min in the algorithm?

Tags: java, sorting, selection

The selection sort always find the minimum value and do swap. But can I delete the intermediate variable, just swap i and j? The original code is below:

```
public static void sort(int[] arr){

    int n = arr.length;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++ ){
        int minIndex = i;
        for( int j = i + 1 ; j < n ; j ++ )
            if( arr[j] < arr[minIndex] )
                minIndex = j;

        swap( arr , i , minIndex);
    }
}

private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}
```

I delete the minIndex and make swap between i and j(see below), it still work. Is this still select sort? and what the advantage we need another variable minIndex?

```
public static void sort(int[] arr){

    int n = arr.length;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++ ){
        for( int j = i + 1 ; j < n ; j ++ )
            if( arr[j] < arr[i] )
                swap( arr , i , j);
    }
}

private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}
```

Comment: yes, it works, but you are doing many more swaps than necessary, which miight be less efficient.

Comment: Thank you. What factors decided we need a new variable when we implement the program ?

Comment: well, the fact that you don't want to do more swaps than necessary. As using only one variable is nearly costless in space, and will help avoiding a growing number of operations.